An ordinary inflection point corresponds to an ordinary cusp of the dual curve
The question comes from Hartshorne's Algebraic Geometry, Chapter IV, exercise 2.3(e). Let $X$ be a curve of degree $d$ in $P^2$. char $k = 0$. Hartshorne states that "An ordinary inflection point of $X$ corresponds to an ordinary cusp of the dual curve $X^{*}$".
My example is the curve $y - x^3 = 0$ in $A^2$. $(0,0)$ is an ordinary inflection point. But the tangent line equation of $X$ is $-3 x_0^2 (x - x_0 z)+ (y - y_0 z) = 0$. So the dual curve in $(P^2)^{*}$ is $[-3 x_0^2 : 1 : 2x_0^3]$. Then the equation of the dual curve is $x^3 + \frac{27}{4} y z^2 = 0$. Coincidently, this gives a cusp at $[0 : 1 : 0]$.
How to prove this statement generally?

Not all tangents contain the origin (draw a picture)! Your equation for the tangent is missing the constant part.
